# JAVA - Check for the nearest object in the panel

Tags: java

I'm developing a simple game where there is a ball and many holes in the panel. I want the ball to move at the nearest hole. How to compute for the distance of the ball to each and every hole in the panel?

Comment: Draw a virtual line to each hole from the ball, measure the length of each line

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

```
nearest_hole = first_hole;
min_distance = distance of nearest_hole;

foreach hole {
  calculate distance between ball an hole
  if (distance < min_distance) {
    min_distance = distance;
    nearest_hole = hole;
  }
}
```

After this loop `nearest_hole` is the target hole.

But however, your question is of poor quality. What did you try and what are holes in a panel?